How to interop with interrupts using .net core (Ubuntu)
I'll need a wrapper (C#) for a C lib. I just don't know which .so I'm chasing down.
I've heard of something from Glib that might have bindings for .netcore that wrap libudev.
I've basically been given an interface that I need to satisfy ...
public interface IInterruptSource
{
    event EventHandler<InterruptEventArgs> OnInterrupt;
    void EnableInterrupts();
    void DisableInterrupts();
}

... and a simulated (untested concept) implementation:
public class SimulatedInterruptSource : IInterruptSource
{
    public event EventHandler<InterruptEventArgs> OnInterrupt;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private bool _interruptsEnabled = false;

    public SimulatedInterruptSource()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); // Example: 1 second interval for timer interrupts
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

    public void EnableInterrupts()
    {
        _interruptsEnabled = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void DisableInterrupts()
    {
        _interruptsEnabled = false;
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_interruptsEnabled)
        {
            OnInterrupt?.Invoke(this, new InterruptEventArgs(SemacorInterruptType.Timer));
        }
    }
}

... with these interrupt types:
public enum InterruptType
{
    Timer,
    Keyboard,
    Network,
    // Add more as needed
}

I am trying to find out if something already exists or if I'm rolling my own.

A down vote and vote to close is not helpful without an explanation.

From the first line it sounds like you are requesting a library, which is off-topic.  From the second line it sounds you are looking for the documentation for glib.  Otherwise I can't make head nor tail of what you are asking for.  Not my vote BTW, but trying to help you understand what you might need to add into the question to get a helpful answer.

It should sound like I'm not sure what I'm looking for so if somebody has a clue to help me out in the end, if something already exists that does what I need, I don't need to roll my and it's completely on topic. And I.
Cannot find documentation.I've only heard and seen a statement or two about it but I cannot find any specific documentation.
